# Network Communication Question

Tags: sockets, networking, communication

I would like to ask a question about network communication.

The Question is:

A server uses the socket interface on the Lunix platform,

and a client uses Winock on the Windows platform.

Can they communicate?

Explain briefly.

I guess the answer is NO.

I guess it is due to the compatibility between 2 different socket interface?!

But I am not sure my estimation is right or not.

So, I hope someone could give me some comments about this questions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Last time I checked (that was when XP came out) is that the WinSock functions were written from Linux socket codes.

Comment: BSD, not Linux, but they're clearly Unix inspired.  But that's not the point, it's that they both do TCP.

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say that WinSock has one API which is mostly compatible with the BSD sockets API but that there's also a Windows specific API which allows you to access functionality that the BSD sockets API doesn't support such as overlapped I/O using I/O Completion Ports, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not right at all.

The APIs are different, but both sockets create packets written to a standard format described in [RFC 793](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html) and lots of subsequent revisions and additions.

Follow that packet format, and implementations written for different platforms and in different languages will talk to each other.

This is the magic of the internet.